# Add keywords that consist of two words to CDT

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

To have custom keywords for I do the following:

- Define a language in the `plugin.xml` and extend GPPLanguage class.
- extend CLanguageKeywords and override getKeywords to return super.getKeywords plus custom keywords:

  ```
  public class MyLanguageKeywords extends CLanguageKeywords {
      public MyLanguageKeywords(ParserLanguage language, IScannerExtensionConfiguration config) {
          super(language, config);
      }

      @Override
      public String[] getKeywords() {
      String[] cppKeywords = super.getKeywords();
          String[] myKeywords = new String[] {
              "input",
              "output",
              "input port",
              "output port",
          };
          return (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(cppKeywords, myKeywords);
      }
  }
  ```
- implement getAdapter() to return an instance of MyLanguageKeywords

This works for "input" and "output", but not for "input port" or "output port". How can I have keyword highlighting for "port" but only in the combinations "input port" or "output port"?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options:

1. Modify CDT's lexer to support keywords containing whitespace. I don't think this is something you can do using the public API, you'd have to modify core CDT classes like `org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.parser.scanner.Lexer`. (Alternatively, you could consider upstreaming a patch to add such support to the lexer.)
2. Use **semantic highlighting** to highlight your whitespace-containing keywords. There's an `org.eclipse.cdt.ui.semanticHighlighting` extension point that allows plugins to provide custom semantic highlighting.

The difference in the user experience would be that lexical highlighting is applied immediately after every keystroke, while semantic highlighting is applied after a short delay after typing stops (since it's more expensive to compute). You can see this effect if you compare how the `override` and `final` keywords are currently highlighted in C++, compared to other keywords: `override` and `final` use semantic highlighting because they're context-sensitive keywords.

I should also mention that whether the second approach works, depends on how your new keywords fit into the grammar. They need to be parsed as `IASTName` in order for semantic highlighting to be applied to them.

Comment: I could just inherit from Lexer and override a method to get the desired behavior, if the class wasn't declared final. I think the CDT code has too many of such restrictions. Forking CDT is undesired in my company, so I will try the second approach.

Comment: @Sadik A patch to remove a `final` from a class where it stands in the way of a plugin, would be considered.

Comment: >>They need to be parsed as IASTName<<  I have a concept very similar to 'struct' (but with two keywords). My parser parses as IASTDeclaration. So this approach won't work then, right?

Comment: @Sadik How are you customizing the parser?

Comment: My source parser class is inherits from GNUCPPSourceParser and is instantiated in my language class's createParser() method. My language class inherits from GPPLanguage.

Comment: @Sadik You could work around it by making your node an `IASTImplicitNameOwner` and creating an `IASTImplicitName` covering the region you want to highlight. It would still require a small CDT source change, to allow contributed semantic highlightings to process implicit names (https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/ui/editor/ContributedSemanticHighlighting.java?h=cdt_9_8#n207), which could be upstreamed.